# Ansible playbook tags with repeated values not working

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible playbook command as below:

```
ansible-playbook \
  -u xxxx \
  --extra-vars "user_pass=yyyy module1_version=09:02:01 module2_version=10:12:10" \
  --tags "module1,version-check,module2,version-check" \
  -i inventories/ \
  --limit "DEV" portal_version_test.yml
```

Notice I'm keeping the repeated tag `version-check` in the command as I need to get the version from each module and do a version check after that. This way I can reuse the version-check task for all my modules.

But this command skips the first instance of version check, instead it executes in the order like module1 -> module2 -> version-check`

Does it mean can't we use the repeated tags in the `ansible-playbook` command?

My playbook is something like:

> name: get version from module1
>   ....
>   tags: module1
>
> name: get version from module2
>   ...
>   tags: module2
>
> name: compare expected and actual version
>   ....
>   tags: version-check

Answer (score 2):

> Does it mean can't we use the repeated tags in the ansible-playbook command?

No, you can not use "repeated" tags.

Tags are used as filters in Ansible, so you tell Ansible what tasks you want to execute.
Order of tags in `--tags` parameter doesn't matter, task are always executed in order of appearance in a playbook.